# Are serial numbers of pen drives are unique and universal?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pen

In my application i need to give permission to given pen drive to be allowed to access or not.
I'm using pen drive's serial number to give permission here i want to know if all pen drive has serial number or not and if they have then the serial number is unique or not.

Comment: Arguably it depends on which serial number you mean (the volume, the partition table, and the hardware all have different serial numbers) but I believe the answer is the same in all cases: no, you can't rely on them being unique.  If the hypothetical bad guy doesn't have access to the pen drive in question you might be OK, but of course in that case you could just as easily stick a key in a file on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [link](http://digfor.blogspot.sg/2012/04/usb-flash-drive-serial-numbers-unique.html) its NOT. you may go through the blog post!

Comment: Info from the linked page: there are many tools that allow to edit, temporarily change or emulate pen drive serial number. Even without these tools cheaper models of pen drives reuse the same serial numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it was unique (which it isn't), you shouldn't give permission based on something that can be easily spoofed.

Comment: It is not about giving something it is of allowing pen drives in system so what should i use it suppose to be serial number.
can u suggest any thing else...??

Comment: I guessed from your question that you required some kind of trust system? Otherwise the serial number wouldn't matter at all and you'd allow USB drives through unconditionally -- in any case serial numbers are not the way to reliably identify what a drive is. In fact, very simple circuits can spoof limited functionality of any device you can imagine.